# Directory structure for huge ansible inventory file

Tags: ansible

Our ansible inventory file is getting bigger and bigger day by day. so we wanted to modularize it with directories and file.
say for example.

```
[webservers]
foo.example.com
bar.example.com

[dbservers]
one.example.com
two.example.com
three.example.com
```

this can be converted into

```
|--production
|  |--WEBSERVERS
|  |  |--webservers
|  |--DBSERVERS
|  |  |--dbservers
```

Where **webservers** is a file;

```
[webservers]
foo.example.com
bar.example.com
```

and **dbservers** is a file;

```
[dbservers]
one.example.com
two.example.com
three.example.com
```

for simple inventory file it works fine. Problem comes when I create group of groups.

like

```
[webservers]
foo.example.com
bar.example.com

[dbservers]
one.example.com
two.example.com
three.example.com

[master:children]
webservers
dbservers
```

I cant imagine a directory structure for this and it. Can someone please guide me to the right tutorial.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ansible supports "dynamic inventories" you can read more about this in here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_inventory.html

#### What is it:

Simple script (python, ruby, shell etc) that produces JSON in a specific format.

#### How can I benefit from it:

Create a folder structure that best reflects your needs, and place your servers config in there. Then create a simple executable file to read those files and output a result.

#### Example:

#### inventory.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import yaml
import json

web = yaml.load(open('web.yml', 'r'))

inventory = { '_meta': { 'hostvars': {} } }

# Individual server configuration
for server, properties in web['servers'].iteritems():
  inventory['_meta']['hostvars'][server] = {}
  inventory['_meta']['hostvars'][server]['ansible_ssh_host'] = properties['ip']

# Magic group for all servers
inventory['all'] = {}
inventory['all']['hosts'] = web['servers'].keys()

# Groups of servers
if 'groups' in web:
  for group, properties in web['groups'].iteritems():
    inventory[group] = {}
    inventory[group]['hosts'] = web['groups'][group]

print json.dumps(inventory, indent=2)
```

web.yml

```
---
servers:
  foo:
    ip: 192.168.42.10
  bar:
    ip: 192.168.42.20

groups:
  webservers:
  - foo
  dbservers:
  - bar
```

Then call your playbook as usuall and you will get the same result as if you would use standart `ini` file.